# Get Media ID dynamically

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am currently working in a project with c# and umbraco CMS. And now im facing some issues one of them is that I don't know how to get the media ID dynamically, please take a look **ID COMES FROM UMBRACO**

```
Media file = new Media(3557);

string url = file.getProperty("umbracoFile").Value.ToString();
string teste = file.getProperty("impressions").Value.ToString();
if (teste == "" || teste == null) { teste = "0"; }
int count= Convert.ToInt32(teste);
file.getProperty("impressions").Value = count+1;

file.Save();
```

Do you  see that 1st line ? Media file= new media(id)? I want to get this id dynamically and I will explain why. I have this handler in order to get the banner clicks on the site. I have 4 images and I want to have a count for how many times the client clicks on them. So for that I can't have the id = 3557 , I need to get the id of the image dynamically.

Comment: Where would you get the ID From? Database? User input? Please give some more details.

Comment: @BojanHrnkas im gettin the id from CMS umbraco.

Comment: I understand that, but how do you decide which ID to take? All of them, or one found in the content, or the one being uploaded at the moment,...

Comment: @BojanHrnkas on click in the image want to get the id so i run this code in order to keep count the image clicks.

Comment: Then I assume you are using an event handler, something like:
protected void imgMyMedia_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ your code }

In that case, you can cast the sender object to your control type, and read any parameter set there. I recon it would be something like this:
MediaControl myMedia = (MediaControl)sender;
int ID = myMedia.MediaId;

or something similar. I am not familiar with the umbraco code and can not be as precise, but this should be about right.

Comment: youre right i can use the sender ! :D thanks for the effort man, really thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using an event handler, something like:

`protected void imgMyMedia_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { your code }`

In that case, you can cast the sender object to your control type, and read any parameter set there. I recon it would be something like this:

`MediaControl myMedia = (MediaControl)sender;
int ID = myMedia.MediaId;`

or something similar. I am not familiar with the umbraco code and can not be as precise, but this should be about right.

Answer (score 0):

When you render the image in the first place you want to put the image id in a data attribute so your html will be something like:

```
<img src="/media/someimage.jpg" data-id="someMediaIdHere" alt="alt" title="title" />
```

Then use that when your javascript picks up the onclick event, then you can pass the image id to the server side and do your tracking.

Comment: Hey , and before anything let me thank you for the effort in order to help me, but u dont seem to understand the question and the tools im using. Im getting the file from umbraco its not as image on aspx, and i can only solve this with c# cant go for jquery or javascript(client demands X) ) but anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry assumed you were using a web project, got any more details on what that method looks like and how it is being called?